# "but only now did i finally do it" vs "but only now i finally did it". why does the first sound better?

Tags: past-tense, present-perfect

> but only now did i finally do it
>
> but only now i finally did it

The first one sounds preferable, but I honestly don't know why. What is the exact grammar behind that kind of positioning of the verbs? Another example of it is something like:

> only in this school have I seen such things happen

Comment: _Only now_ and _only then_ are normally followed by a verb in inverted form (and _only in x place_, as you say), but you can say _It was only now that I finally did it_.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> [a] but only now did i finally do it

> [b] but only now i finally did it

Example (a) demonstrates a type of subject-auxiliary inversion called negative inversion.

Such an inversion happens when a sentence begins with certain types of expressions containing a negation.

> At no time will Sam relax. - Negative inversion

In our example, *only now* is such an expression, and hence subject-auxiliary inversion is needed.

There are exceptions, i.e., some fronted expressions with negation do not cause an inversion.  Details can be found in [Wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Negative_inversion).